# Почему приложение запускается при подключении устройства?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms

В Xamarin.Forms при подключении USB-устройства у пользователя запрашивается разрешение на использование устройства. И это происходит каждый раз при подключении устройства. Это надоедает. Я сделал следующее: создал файл device_filter.xml, в который ввел данные об устройстве:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="some_vendor_id" product-id="some_product_id" />
</resources>
```

И в MainActivity.cs добавил следующие атрибуты:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached })]
[MetaData(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached, Resource = "@xml/device_filter")]
```

Это сработало. Теперь запрашивается доступ только при первом подключении, но при этом происходит следующее: при подключении устройства запускается приложение, если оно не было запущено. Как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте спросить тут https://t.me/xamarin_russia может подскажут

Comment: Попробую. Благодарю.